# could not run programs on eclipse android

Tags: android

I am facing some problem while running my android program.It was working fine, recently I upgraded to android 3.1 ( window->android sdk and avd ->available packages , and installed).
Now when i try to run, it is giving following error.

```
'Launching New_Configuration' has encountered a problem.  An Internel error occured during 'Launching New_Configuration' 
Details >> An internal error occurred during: "Launching New_configuration".
com/android/ddmlib/InstallException
```

Kindly help me to solve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 20):

At some point the update has changed your run configuration to "New_configuration"

Next to run click the down arrow (or otherwise navigate to "Run As") and simply re-select Android Application

Comment: This worked. In my case, this seemed to be the issue.

Answer (score 12):

To solve this I went to:

> **RUN > RUN CONFIGURATIONS** > Android Application  > [new_configuration]

Selected the new configuration, on the right panel:

> NAME: [input the project name]
>
> BROWSE: for the project you want to launch

Then run.

You need to configure the target base on your preference then you are okey.. :D

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

it's very simple 
you just delete new configuration from
**RUN > RUN CONFIGURATIONS > Android Application > [new_configuration] **

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Eclipse fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

RUN > RUN CONFIGURATIONS > Android Application > [new_configuration] > Android

In a field Project select Browse and choose your project

Comment: This does not provide any further information than http://stackoverflow.com/a/12658683/3202885

Answer (score 0):

In my Case Prefer to run the application as following instead of using "Run New_configuration" icon and run the application smoothly:-
Select "Run as" -> Android Application
my error was:
[image]